# Updating source mappings

Tags: tfs

I am using the TFS2018 api to copy the source mappings from my XAML build definitions to the new build definition. I have the following code

```
var def = defs.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == xamlDef.Name);
if (def != null)
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mappings);
    var tfvs = json.Replace("$(SourceDir)", "");       
    def.Repository.Properties["tfvcMapping"] = tfvs;
    using (var buildClient = new BuildHttpClient(uri, cred))
    {
        var t = buildClient.UpdateDefinitionAsync(def, teamProject);
        var result = t.Result;
    }
}
```

The tfvs variable contains the following string

```
{"mappings":[{"serverPath":"$/Utils/TestQueue","mappingType":"map","localPath":"\Utils\TestQueue"},{"serverPath":"$/MyTeamProject/ProjectA","mappingType":"map","localPath":"\MyTeamProject\ProjectA"}]}
```

After I update the source mapping are not there. If I look at the build definition it only contains the following string

```
{[tfvcMapping, {"mappings":[{"serverPath":"$/MyTeamProject","mappingType":"map","localPath":"\\"}]}]}
```

Is the tfvcMapping string incorrect? Is it maybe not possible to update the source mappings using the tfs api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can update source mappings using the tfs api, the api is [Update a build definition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#update-a-build-definition).

The following is an example of JSON file for source mapping, you can check it:

```
"tfvcMapping": "{\"mappings\":[{\"serverPath\":\"$/TestCase/TestCase1\",\"mappingType\":\"map\",\"localPath\":\"\\\\TestCase1\"},{\"serverPath\":\"$/TestCase/TestCaseProject\",\"mappingType\":\"map\",\"localPath\":\"\\\\TestCaseProject\"}]}"
```

Comment: How can I do this on TFS 2017 U3?  (no 4.1 rest api)  Right now i'm trying to use JObject to parse the value field json, update it and then copy the whole property.  Then I  think I will need to delete the property and add the new property?