# Add/Update BuildDefinition.Repository.Properties.tfvcMapping using BuildHttpClient - TFS 2017 U3

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

This question is very similar to this post: [Updating source mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261834/updating-source-mappings) but I'm trying to use the BuildHttpClient instead of calling the RestAPI directly.

The end goal is to create a copy of a build/release definition and use it for a different application.

The 'dr' object i'm passing along is a datarow that contains the data I'd like to use to update the build definition.  Here is the ClientConnection Code:

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(serverUrl, new VssCredentials());
BuildHttpClient bdClient = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();

// using Wait on the task
Task<BuildDefinition> templateTask = bdClient.GetDefinitionAsync(teamProjectName, IDtoClone);
templateTask.Wait();
BuildDefinition updatedDefinition = ReplaceBuildParameters(templateTask.Result, dr);
Task<BuildDefinition> updatedTask =  bdClient.CreateDefinitionAsync(updatedDefinition, teamProjectName);
updatedTask.Wait();
return updatedTask.Result;
```

**Update**

Based on Andy's feedback below I've updated the code.  Instead of trying to update the property object i'm replacing it.  I think i have this working, I've got a few tests left to verify.  I'm trying to use JObject to get to the value and update it after modification.

```
   private static BuildDefinition ReplaceBuildParameters(BuildDefinition resultDef, DataRow dr)
    {
        resultDef.Name = "myCreateBuildAttempt";
        resultDef.Path = "\\Templates\\POCSandbox";
            foreach (DataColumn column in dr.Table.Columns)
            {
                switch (column.ColumnName)
                {
                    case "ServerPath":

                    JObject tfvcObj = new JObject();
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> prop in resultDef.Repository.Properties)
                    {
                        if (prop.Key == "tfvcMapping")
                        {
                            KeyValuePair<string, string> myPath = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("serverPath", "$/MASTER/PRES");
                            tfvcObj = JObject.Parse(prop.Value);
                            var mappings = tfvcObj["mappings"];
                            JToken myToken = JToken.Parse(mappings[0].ToString());
                            myToken["serverPath"] = "$/MASTER/PRES";
                            mappings[0] = myToken;
                            tfvcObj["mappings"] = mappings;
                        }
                    }
                    resultDef.Repository.Properties["tfvcMapping"] = tfvcObj.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);

                    break; 

                    default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        return resultDef;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can also use the REST API with `api-version=3.2` to update source mappings in TFS 2017 U3.

You can use below PowerShell sample to add/update the source mapping:

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "http://tfs2017-test:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection",
   [string]$project = "ProjectName",
   [string]$definitionid = "6",
   [string]$user = "Domain\username",
   [string]$token = "Password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#Get resonse of the build definition
$defurl = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/build/definitions/$($definitionid)?api-version=3.2"            
$definition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $defurl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

#Set repository.properties, source mapping for example:
$definition.repository.properties.tfvcMapping = '{"mappings":[{"serverPath":"$/ScrumProject/Dev","mappingType":"map","localPath":"\\"}]}'

$json = @($definition) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99

#Update build definition
$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri $defurl  -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

You can also use the TFS BuildHttpClient to Update the build Definition, please reference this thread for details: https://serverfault.com/questions/799607/tfs-buildhttpclient-updatedefinition-c-example

Comment: is there a way to do this with the build HTTP client or do I need to switch over to the rest API?

Comment: @gperrego Reference this thread : https://serverfault.com/questions/799607/tfs-buildhttpclient-updatedefinition-c-example

Comment: yes I have the httpbuild client working and I can create a new build definition without issue.  I can change the name, update/add/remove variables ect but the problem is how to change the repository properties, specifically the mappings via the httpclient.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The code above works, it was a JSON parsing issue.  I hope this example helps others.  When I'm doing with this project I'll see about hosting the full solution on GitHub.